# Getting "'Nonetype' object is not iterable" while using Click Element from Appium Library in RF

Tags: robotframework

**Use case :**
I am trying to click an element on mobile screen using Xpath locator

**Code :**
This is a sample code how I am trying to use `Click element` across different combination of Xpath or id.

```python
*** Settings ***
Library          AppiumLibrary
Library          Collections

*** Variables ***
${xpath1}    //android.widget.Button[contains(@text,'ACCEPT')]

*** Test Cases ***
Open_Dialer_test
    Open_Dialer

*** Keywords ***
Open_Dialer
    #sleep  20s
    #Get Selection From User    Input any value
    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Click Element    ${xpath1}
    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Click Element    xpath://android.widget.ToggleButton[@content-desc='Answer']
    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Click Element    xpath://*[@resource-id='android:id/action0']
```

**Result**
For each combination , I am getting **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable**
What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is between latest robotframework version 3.1 and **robotframework-appium** library.

The latest **RF** code is taking the argument passed to KW like **Click element** as **none**.
As a result we are getting error **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable**

**Solution :**

1. Uninstalled robotframework
2. Installed the previous stable version for me by using command

   pip install robotframework==3.0.4